# Joomla - how can I count all active instances of specific module type?

Tags: joomla

As the title suggests my question is pretty simple.
Is there a way to count the total number of active module instances of a specific type/kind in Joomla (with a specific module name)?

I know how to count modules in a specific module position using JModuleHelper::getModules, but that is not what I want.
I simply need to count all active modules instances of a specific type/kind.

Does anyone know how to do this (without having to do a manual MySQL query)?

Comment: what is a module type?

Comment: By "module type" I mean the name of the module (not the title of the module instances)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is an official joomla way, but you can do it by having an sql query looking at

#__modules

table.

Check out this table and you will find out how easy it is.

An example sql would be:

```
select count(id) from #__modules where module = 'mod_login'
```

Comment: That does not tell me whether or not there are any module instances on page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no joomla method for this. I would recommend (if it has to be done) either

- using a crawler to go through all pages of the site counting the instances.
- or using a script which goes through the template php files and the database to find all active instances.

Both these methods might not be 100% reliable due to unexpected circumstances (like module being included in article or module included only after a button is clicked on) but could work if you know your site well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be such a function in Joomla.
In my case I needed this to tell me whether or not a instances of this module was > 0  or not.. and my alternative solution was to simply make a module-specific function and then in the module php file check if function is already loaded.